# How to create an instance of an object which has strftime method?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def some_method(start, end):
  a = 'items?from=%s&to=%s' % (start.strftime('%Y%m%d'), end.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
  # ....
```

What should I pass to some_method? I've tried these:

```
some_method("20000101", "20140902")
some_method(20000101, 20140902)
some_method(time.strptime("30 Nov 00"), time.strptime("30 Nov 05"))
```

but none of these worked due a type mismatch error. The documentation didn't work me either (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime).

Answer (score 2):

You need a [`datetime.datetime()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime); these have a [`datetime.datetime.strftime()` methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). You could also use a [`datetime.date` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date); these have the [same method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 3, 19, 40, 38, 174720)
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20140903'
>>> datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20140903'
```

The [`datetime.time()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) has one too, but you cannot use the `'%Y%m%d'` format on those as they don't have the required date information.

And did you know the [Python documentation has a search feature](https://docs.python.org/2/search.html?q=strftime&check_keywords=yes&area=default)?  The above 3 types-with-`strftime`-methods are the first 3 hits.

Comment: Also https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.date.strftime

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an object of class [struct_time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time).

You can create one from a string using time.strptime like this: `time.strptime("30 Nov 00", "%d %b %y")`, passing a second argument with the time format; or using [gmtime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.gmtime) or [localtime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime).

The way to use strftime then is passing that object as the second parameter:

```
start = time.strptime("30 Nov 00", "%d %b %y")
print time.strftime('%Y%m%d', start)
```